# Can structs really not be null in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, nullable

Below is some code that demonstrates I cannot declare and initialize a struct type as null.  The [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type is a struct, so why am I able to set it to null?

```
Nullable<bool> b = null;
if (b.HasValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("HasValue == true");
}

//Does not compile...
Foo f = null;
if (f.HasValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("HasValue == true");
}
```

Where `Foo` is defined as

```
public struct Foo
{
    private bool _hasValue;
    private string _value;

    public Foo(string value)
    {
        _hasValue = true;
        _value = value;
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get { return _hasValue; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}
```

The question has been answered (see below).  To clarify I'll post an example.  The C# code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Nullable<bool> a;
        Nullable<bool> b = null;
    }
}
```

produces the following IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       10 (0xa)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool> a,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool> b)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldloca.s   b
  IL_0003:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
  IL_0009:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

a and b are declared, but only b is initialized.

Comment: @Forgotten Semicolon, not the point of the question.

Comment: If you're still curious, try executing `b.GetType()` after you've successfully shown that `b.HasValue` is false.  This demonstrates one way in which a nullable type is not the same as a struct, since you can dereference the 'null' nullable to access HasValue or even the Equals method, but any operation that boxes the nullable will return a true null.

Comment: @Dan.  Yup, I see what you are talking about.  Nullable<T>.HasValue returns false, but Nullable<T>.GetType() throws an exception because it is attempting to get the type of the wrapped value...

Comment: actually, if you call GetType on an `int?` for example, you'll get `typeof(Nullable<int>)` as the result.  The real issue is that GetType() cannot be overridden, so the value is boxed to an Object before the method is called.  Since the CLR boxes the Nullable value type to a a true null (a special behavior it does only for Nullable types), this causes an exception.  You'll see the same behavior any time you pass the Nullable type to a method that takes an Object.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The C# compiler provides you with a bit of sugar so you really are doing this:

```
Nullable<bool> b = new Nullable<bool>();
```

Here is the syntactic sugar

```
bool? b = null;    
if (b ?? false) 
{
   b = true;
}
```

Comment: You are correct.  Viewing it in ILDASM answers it.  Have any references from MS on the matter?  This is news to me...

Comment: @Nate, The C# language specification has some details on how Nullable types are handled.  It's worth noting that Nullable Value types are not structures; structures and Nullables are both Value types, but the compiler and CLR give different treatment to each.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552

Comment: @Dan, the reason for the question was I was using a bool? and wondered to myself if I needed to check if the Nullable<T> wrapper it was in was null before referencing Nullable<T>.HasValue.  I was surprised to find out that I did not.  I had thought Nullable<T> was a class type, but discovered it was a struct when reading its definition.  That got me to wondering why I could set a Nullable<T> to null but not a "regular" struct.

Answer (score 15):

C# has some syntax sugar that allows you to appear to set a nullable type to `null`.  What you are *actually* doing under the covers is setting the nullable type's `HasValue` property to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not actually setting the `Nullable<T>` variable to `null`. The struct is still there. It represents `null` via an internal bit flag in the struct.

There's also some compiler sugar to make magic happen behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a structure to null, but you can have implicit type conversions, which is what is happening under the hood.

Comment: This is actually more than just an implicit type conversion.  The CLR provides special support for Nullable types which make them a bit different from other value types.  The biggest difference is that a 'null' Nullable is boxed to a true null reference and unboxing null will create a new Nullable that equates to null.